# How to read a picture from an url that contains an auto-download picture on Android?

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp, android-glide

I have an issue when trying to show on UI a picture from a link with auto-download. Picasso and Glide do not know how to open that. They are looking for an address.

For instance, I have this picture  https://graph.facebook.com/10155174010491889/picture?type=large. When you access the link, you automatically get a downloaded picture. Picasso doesn't know how to handle this.

I studied this issue (https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/463), applied the OkHttpClient and the downloader, but it still doesn't work:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
Downloader downloader = new OkHttp3Downloader(client);

        new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(downloader)
                .listener((picasso, uri, exception) -> {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "loadImageWithPicasso: " + exception);
                })
                .build()
                .load(Uri.parse(path))
                .centerCrop()
                .fit()
                .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(ImageUtils.roundedCornersImage(context, imageView));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        imageView.setImageResource(resourceDrawable);
                    }
                });
```

I have even tried separately to make an OkHTTP request to that image and get weird results - bitmap null (when trying to download as bitmap), network response redirect url image with 0 size (https://m.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=10155174010491889&height=200&width=200)

```
getRequest("https://graph.facebook.com/10155174010491889/picture?type=large", new okhttp3.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    Log.d(TAG, "body = " + response.body());
                    Log.d(TAG, "network response = " + response.networkResponse().toString());
                    InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                    Log.d(TAG, response.networkResponse().request().url() + " <<<<");

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                }

            });
        }
    }

    public static void getRequest(String url, okhttp3.Callback callback) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .get()
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }
```

I saw that Postman opens the picture with a simple GET, without any issue implied.

What can you suggest me as a solution to this situation?

Comment: I tried your url in one of my projects, `Glide` loaded it without any problems

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan, can you please share the little code snippet? I have also tried with Glide and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

There you go !
**Glide Version 3.5.2**

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("https://graph.facebook.com/10155174010491889/picture?type=large")
.centerCrop().listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, 
                    String model, 
                    Target<GlideDrawable> target, 
                    boolean isFirstResource) {
                        spinKitView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, 
                    String model, 
                    Target<GlideDrawable> target, 
                    boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        spinKitView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                }).into(profile_picture);
```

Comment: it is so weird. Yesterday it did not work for hours with Picasso or Glide and today suddenly works with both of them, no code change... Probably facebook issues...

Comment: It proved to be a facebook temporary issue at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your link work perfectly in **Glide** 4.6.1

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load("https://graph.facebook.com/10155174010491889/picture?type=large")
     .into(imageview);
```

Comment: @Nijunj, thank you for the answer. As I was stating earlier to Ionut J. Bejan, it is a very weird behavior. Yesterday I tested for hours with both Picasso and Glide and I got this message "java.io.IOException: Failed to decode stream" and now everything is working just fine, as you stated. It was certainly a facebook issue. Probably they come from time to time.

Can you please upvote my question if you found it interesting?